# Cannot open browser from ssh terminal

Tags: ubuntu, browser, ssh

I've been trying a few ways to open up a browser from an SSH terminal for web app testing. Here is what I've tried and what the issues are with that method. If anyone knows how to fix one or all of these, I'd appreciated it. I am starting this ssh session with `-X`, so that's not the issue.

1)

```
firefox http://www.google.com
```

Returns

`Error: cannot open display: :0`

2)

```
gnome-open http://google.com
```

Returns

```
(gnome-open:5281): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11     initialization failed.

GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running

my_username@ip-my-ip:~$ 
(process:5286): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

3)

```
sensible-browser http://google.com
```

Returns

```
(process:5292): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :0
None of the browsers in $BROWSER worked!
```

Thanks

Comment: I deleted my post since I misread your intention. You want to open up the graphical browser, not to run it in headless mode, right?

Comment: Yeah I just want to be able to run my app on localhost on the server and open up a browser I can check it out in

Comment: Yes, I've seen that d-bus problem. And I've fixed it by starting the messagebus service. Finding the service name now.

Comment: try `sudo service dbus start` and if it works run `firefox -no-remote`

Comment: Same error - Error:cannot open display :10

Comment: is yr X11 forwarding enabled in /etc/ssh/ssh_config file? Search for something like `ForwardX11` and set it to yes. Then restart the ssh service by `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: lastly just check `echo $DISPLAY` and if it doesn't match the one from the error message, export it by `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: Still nothing. X11 Forwarding is set to yes, and I restarted ssh. Still same error...

Comment: hmm, the problem I had only involved 'display error'. Sorry I can't help more. And last guess is to play around with permissions. I will try this on my machine tho.